# Robot Framework Succeed on Exception

Tags: exception, testing, robotframework

I am testing a software component and want that software to throw an Exception in certain situations. 
I want to reproduce these situations by using the robot framework.

- The testcase shall succeed if I catch a specific Exception (which I am expecting, because I am deliberately creating an error-state in my component under test)
- The testcase shall fail if I do not receive the specific Exception (i.e. my component under test did not fail(throw an exception) in an error situation)

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
prepareErrorInTestEnvironment
try 
    executeComponentWhichThrowsException
except
    pass
fail
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treatment of "expected exception" are a bit specific in Robot Framework as usually exception will fail the keyword and hence the test.
The keyword you are looking for is [Run Keyword and Expect Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Expect%20Error).

Your test would look like

```
*** Test Cases ***
my test
    prepareErrorInTestEnvironment
    Run Keyword and Expect Error  TheExceptionYouExpect  executeComponentWhichThrowsException
```

This will success if you get the proper exception, and fail otherwise

Comment: How do we achieve a flow where the test-case (here "executeComponentWhichThrowsException" is clean and might not be generating any exception ... This Keyword is forcefully expecting an Error on remote side. In case when "executeComponent" does not generate any exception this keyword returns "test case Expected error 'safeException:*' did not occur."

Answer (score 0):

I believe `try/else` is what you want

```
prepareErrorInTestEnvironment
try:
    executeComponentWhichThrowsException
except:
    pass
else: 
    fail
```

Also you can return on except so fail will not execute:

```
prepareErrorInTestEnvironment
try:
    executeComponentWhichThrowsException
except:
    *dosomething*
    return
fail
```

Comment: I think my "python" tag was a bit misleading, as I was actually looking for a robotframework solution
thanks for the reply
I will remove the "python" flag, as my question is not unique to robotframework with python only